# What is the difference between volatility and evaporation?

Tags: vapor-pressure

I've been trying to find the difference between volatility and evaporation and I can see almost everywhere that the volatility is the tendency of a substance to vaporize. So **Q1**: what makes the volatility special? I understand that the fuels are generally volatile, and I understand that they vaporize faster than water, for example. But **Q2**: is this the only difference?

I was thinking that volatility also makes the vapor have a different chemical composition, or did I get it wrong?

For instance, the water (a non-volatile liquid) vapor is still $\ce{H2O}$, right? **Q3:** Will the vapor of benzene $\ce{C6H6}$ still be $\ce{C6H6}$ or it brakes into other compounds?

Comment: No it's still going to be benzene vapour.

Comment: **Q2:** Yeah vaporised water is still H2O but not H2O(aq), vaporised water is H2O(g). This is called **change of state** **Q3:** this is also true for the C6H6(g)

Comment: Thank you, both. So basically volatile substances are substances with low molecular forces and that's all, true? Nothing special with them when speaking about vaporization. Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Evaporate* is a phase change from liquid to gas without changing the molecule itself (or the atoms is the liquid is atomic).

*Volatility* is essentially the tendency of a liquid to evaporate. So a highly volatile liquid would show a great tendency to evaporate.

A measure of volatility is the *vapor pressure*. There is a very related term *partial pressure*. So if we think of air as being nitrogen and oxygen, then there is a partial pressure for nitrogen and a partial pressure for oxygen, and the sum of the two partial pressure is the actual pressure (the absolute pressure).

To make things a bit more confusing chemists think of absolute pressure. So because we are in earth's atmosphere there is always *1 atmosphere* of gas pressure. So when you pump a car tire up to 30 lbs/sq inch, there is already 14.7 lbs /sq inch air pressure due to the atmosphere. So the absolute pressure inside the tire is 44.7 lbs/sq inch.